# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined jquery.js:2

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am having trouble tracking down where this error came from. I am building a Wordpress site and receiving this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined jquery.js:2

I've read around for what could be causing it. jQuery is included only once on the page and before all dependencies. Also, I am not actually using the replace function in the site except for line 20 of scripts.js which came with the theme and had been working fine.

Any ideas how I could track down where this issue is originating? Here's the site: http://www.standardissuedesign.com/new/

Thanks!

Comment: start by using browser console to check for errors... page throws syntax error as soon as it loads

Comment: Throws error for me to, faulty closing of a function on line 163.

Comment: hey i was messing with it, sorry. it is only throwing the error that i mentioned at this point.

Comment: just discovered that if I comment out lines 34 to 39 of scripts.js, the error disappears. not sure what's wrong within there though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it - it was a simple syntax error. I had:

```
$("a[href]:not[rel='same']").click(function(e) {
```

when I should have had:

```
$("a[href]:not(a[rel='same'])").click(function(e) {
```

Thanks for the help!